# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shippingAddress') in checkout Magento 2.4.5 p2

Tags: magento2, checkout

[image]I am getting these errors in Magento checkout 2.4.5p2

caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quoteData')  quote.js
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'storeCode')   url-builder.js

Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder.js

Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote.js